# Print a part of string that made a string match regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check if my `String` contains any letters(N S W E - map directions). And if it does I want to set `direction = that letter` and return either true or false.

Example:

input:
`15.15.15 N`

output I want to receive:
`N`

output that `direction = matcher.group();` gives me:
`15.15.15 N`

As expected it prints string that matched the regex. I want to print only the part that made it matched. Letter can be at beginning or at the end of the string. Any idea how to make it?

```
public boolean example (String value) {

    Pattern parrent = Pattern.compile(".*[a-zA-Z].*");
    Matcher matcher = parrent.matcher(value);        

    if(matcher.find()) {
        direction = matcher.group();
        System.out.println("direction" + direction);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does it mean you want to obtain the first `N`, `S`, `W`, or `E` in the string? You may easily get it with [`s.replaceFirst("(?s)^(?:[^NSWE]*([NSWE]).*|.*)", "$1")`](http://ideone.com/nWtzQq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a [group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) there!

Try this here instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".* (N|S|W|E)");
```

The point is: you basically have

*non-whitespace whatever*

a space

one of four letters which you are interested in.

Thus you want a simple pattern that ignores anything you don't care about; and **groups** around the element you want back.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I just needed to change your regex to `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[NSWE]");`

Comment: You are welcome; I am glad you found even a shorter solution that works for you.